# can't find my windows partition files in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows

i have recently started using ubuntu and i dont know where to find the files from my earlier installed windows in ubuntu i had huge datas in previous partitons in D and E drive

Comment: can you open a terminal and type in `sudo fdisk -l` and add the output to your post.

Comment: in ubuntu, they are not labled D and E, they are named stuff like /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 or something else

Answer (score 0):

If they are on a partition? Sometimes you have to specifically mount it before you can access the files.

If that's the case, go to disks, select the partition you have your data on and then hit the little play button to mount it. from there you should be able to access things on the partition from the normal file system.